# iPad firebug lite or similar

Tags: html, ipad, firebug

I have read lots of blogs about how to get firebug lite to work on the iPad and from what i can gather it worked at some point but hasn't worked in awhile. I can't get it to work myself.

**So my question is has anyone gotten firebug lite or something simliar to work on the iPad recently**. With the iPad being so popular I find it amazing that there isn't a good solid developer tool out there for it yet. Especially because in my experience it doesn't render web pages as expected quite often and needs specific tweaking.

Just to stop some quick replies, I already know its a webkit browser and the issues that I have spotted only show up on the iphone and ipad, not in chrome or desktop safari. So i really would love a solution that is native to the ipad itself.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion below worked for me on an iPad3 running IOS6.

This technique is from http://www.jamesmacfie.com/2012/03/debug-your-html-css-on-the-ipadiphone/

Bookmark any site on iPad then edit the address. Paste in the following code:

```
  javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E.{if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Remote Debugging with Chrome browser. However iOS 6 comes with built-in support for remote debugging - [link](http://www.screenr.com/GYZ8).

Comment: The video you linked to had no sound and showed (i believe) using Safari with user agent set to IOS which isn't helpful. The page i am working on looks correct in safari with the user agent set to IOS it does not however look correct on an actual ipad

Comment: It looks like there is some better developer tools in safari 6 but it also looks like its only for mac. Suffice to say that just won't do.

Comment: Apple really likes to break the interface and this is no longer possible with iOS 14.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed this many times (and in the past month on the new iPad) and it has worked.

http://martinkool.com/post/13629963755/firebug-on-ipad-and-iphone

FYI: The directions might be a little outdated so don't give up. What you will be doing is creating a bookmark. Then you edit the link in the bookmark with the script on Martin's website. That also means Firebug Lite can be used on Internet Explorer...although I couldn't edit any elements after getting it up and running.

Good luck!